# What does it mean that a spanning set can form a plane?

Tags: linear-algebra

From what I know, If you have $3$ linearly independent vectors and the vectors have a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Then you will form a basis. However, it is not always the case that you will have $3$ independent vectors, so it will not have a spanning set of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Sometimes the "spanning set can form a plane or a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$". I have no idea what this means, has it got something to do with the dimensionality of the vector space? Can you explain it to me assuming I am a beginner at this.

Thank you

Comment: $\text{span} \{u\}$ is the set of all linear combinations of $u$, i.e. $2u, -5u$. It is a linear space, can you see it forms a line determined by $u?$

Comment: Take the vectors $i,j,k$. They span all of $R^3$, right? Now take the vectors $i,j,i+j$. What subspace of $R^3$ do they span?

Comment: If $u,v$ are any two vectors in $R^3$, the span of $\{u,v\}$ is not all of $R^3$. The span will be $\{0\}$ if $u=v=0$, or a line through the origin if $u,v$ are linearly dependent, but not both zero, or a plane through the origin if $u,v$ are linearly independent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider how many coordinates it takes to uniquely define a point in a plane, or a line for that matter. For a plane it's $2$, for a line it's $1$.

Thus given two linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R^3}$: $u$, $v$; we can define a plane where the coordinates $(a,b)$ are defined as $au + bv$, and the subspace in which the points lie is the plane containing the vectors $u$ and $v$. Conversely, any point that lies in that plane can be written as a linear combination of $u$ and $v$, and that is what is meant by "$u$ and $v$ span the plane"

Same for a single vector w in $\mathbb{R^3}$, the coordinate (c) can be defined as $cw$, and hence the the subspace this defines is the line that passes through the origin and $cw$. Likewise, any point in that line can be written as a scalar multiple of $w$. That is what is meant by "$w$ spans the line"

Since the dimension of a vector space is equal to the greater number of linearly independent vectors in that space, the plane (which has a maximum of two independent vectors) has dimension 2, and a line (which has at most one independent vector) has dimension 1.